# Implicit Intent to Dial a number in android - ACTION_DIAL and ACTION_CALL

Tags: android, android-intent, implicit

I am using this code to dial a number. But when i use the button to execute the code Skype messenger gets opened. Why?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+918053623401"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But when i use these codes below, When i replace ACTION_CALL by ACTION_DIAL then the codes are working fine. Can any one tell me why?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+918053623401"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And also can anyone give me the codes of adding CHOOSER in case of dialing a numer using implicit intent? Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2):

Skype, like any other app, can register an Intent-Filter to be triggered when an `ACTION_CALL` or `ACTION_DIAL` is requested.
The reason why Skype is automatically opening, is because:

1. Skype is the only app on your device that registered the `ACTION_CALL`.
2. You manually set Skype as the default app to use for the `ACTION_CALL`.
   You can reset this behavior on the settings of your device. Go to App manager, select the Skype app, and `erase default action`

Use this to create an Intent Chooser:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(yourIntent, "Select an app"));
```

Comment: @user3763594 did it solves your issue? If so, mark this answer as the correct one ;)